# Mongo query to group and count by one field and also get the count of other 2 fields based on first count

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In  my mongodb, i have a collection, i want to create a new collection by comparing the collection 1 and collection 2 using pymongo.

I have a mongo collection as shown below:
        Collection 1 :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("7a563a5a5560fd08da86dc46"), "UUID" : 8123, "timestamp" : ISODate("2018-01-10T16:08:26.613Z"), "SUBJECT_ID" : "Maths", "Group": CS, "UNO": 1, "Audited": "True"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("7a563a5a5560fd08da86dc47"), "UUID" : 8123, "timestamp" : ISODate("2018-01-10T16:08:26.613Z"), "SUBJECT_ID" : "Maths, A1", "Group": CS, "UNO": 1, "Audited": "False"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("7a563a5a5560fd08da86dc47"), "UUID" : 8124, "timestamp" : ISODate("2018-01-10T16:08:26.613Z"), "SUBJECT_ID" : "Maths, A1", "Group": CS, "UNO": 2, "Audited": "False"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("7a563a5a5560fd08da86dc47"), "UUID" : 8123, "timestamp" : ISODate("2018-01-16T16:08:26.613Z"), "SUBJECT_ID" : "Maths, A1", "Group": CS, "UNO": 2, "Audited": "False"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("7a563a5a5560fd08da86dc47"), "UUID" : 8124, "timestamp" : ISODate("2018-01-10T16:08:26.613Z"), "SUBJECT_ID" : "Maths, A1", "Group": BS, "UNO": 3, "Audited": "True"}
```

So I want to group and count by field Group and also get the count of true or false  and list of UNO under true and false for each group, below is the output i would want.

```
{"Group": "CS", group_count : "3",  "True_count" :"1", "True_UNO_list": [1], "False_count": 2, "False_UNO_List: [1,2]}
{"Group": "BS", group_count : "1",  "True_count" :"1", "True_UNO_list": [3], "False_count": 0, "False_UNO_List: []}
```

Here 4th entry is a duplicate because UUID, UNO and Audited is same as 2nd entry just the timestamp is different hence i do not want to add it int the output collection.

Is it poosible to achieve in one aggregate query and how would that be ?

Comment: Are you still looking for help ? also I can see UNO is different for 4 & 2, Plus when you say compare collection 1 and collection 2 can you give us collection 2 as well and what you would like to do with that.